# Use memo and PureComponent (Performance of React App)

Tags: jquery, reactjs

In this small react app.
Do you think that `<ComponentB>` will re-render if only `props.propA` changes value?

```
const MyApp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentA propA={props.propA}/>
      <ComponentB propB={props.propB}/>
    </div>
  );
};

const ComponentA = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.propA}</div>
};

const ComponentB = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.propB}</div>
};
```

Comment: `<ComponentB>` will re-render

Comment: React will re-render ```<ComponentB>```, you can use ```memo``` to prevent this, or return ```false``` from ```ShouldComponentUpdate``` in class components